# Creating virtual environment on Linux

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv, virtual-environment

I have Python 3.8.10 installed on my Ubuntu 20. My Linux is installed on an SSD and I have a HD, where I created a partition. In this HD partition I am trying to create a virtual environment using venv but this error appears Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'lib' -> '/media/marcos/VOLUME/Ajuda Mestrado/venv/lib64'

I have checked the python version and tried to create the environment using: python3 -m venv venv, but it didn't resolve

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be **Sharing of Resources** check the following:

-Avoid system directories or shared folders (like VirtualBox shared folders) due to restrictions.

-Create the virtual environment in a non-shared folder with write permissions.

Answer (score -1):

Try running as root.

`sudo python3 -m venv venv`